# My ArrayList prints the same object twice

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi

I am reading excel sheet and storing in array list. It is storing. But when i am printing array list objects , it prints same data. Please help me.

Java Code:-

```
public class ExcelHelper 
{   
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public void initialize(String workbookName) 
    {
        try 
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(workbookName);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            Sheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            int noOfRows = sh.getLastRowNum();

            for(int j=1; j<=noOfRows; j++)
            {
                String operation = sh.getRow(j).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase("ADD"))
                {
                    String firstName = sh.getRow(j).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
                    String lastName = sh.getRow(j).getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
                    int age = (int)sh.getRow(j).getCell(4).getNumericCellValue();
                    String gender = sh.getRow(j).getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
                    int salary = (int)sh.getRow(j).getCell(6).getNumericCellValue();
                    String department = sh.getRow(j).getCell(7).getStringCellValue();
                    String state = sh.getRow(j).getCell(8).getStringCellValue();
                    String city = sh.getRow(j).getCell(9).getStringCellValue();
                    String address = sh.getRow(j).getCell(10).getStringCellValue();
                    String email = sh.getRow(j).getCell(11).getStringCellValue();
                    String skills = sh.getRow(j).getCell(12).getStringCellValue();

                    employee.setOperation(operation);
                    employee.setFirstName(firstName);
                    employee.setLastName(lastName);
                    employee.setAge(age);
                    employee.setGender(gender);
                    employee.setSalary(salary);
                    employee.setDepartment(department);
                    employee.setState(state);
                    employee.setCity(city);
                    employee.setAddress(address);
                    employee.setEmail(email);
                    employee.setSkillSet(skills);

                    System.out.println(firstName);    //Nadn Rohit
                    employeeList.add(employee);
                    System.out.println(employeeList.get(j-1).getFirstName()+" from EX");   //Nadn from EX    Rohit from EX

                }
                else if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase("MOD"))
                {
                    int id = (int)sh.getRow(j).getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
                    String firstName = sh.getRow(j).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
                    String lastName = sh.getRow(j).getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
                    int age = (int)sh.getRow(j).getCell(4).getNumericCellValue();
                    String gender = sh.getRow(j).getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
                    int salary = (int)sh.getRow(j).getCell(6).getNumericCellValue();
                    String department = sh.getRow(j).getCell(7).getStringCellValue();
                    String state = sh.getRow(j).getCell(8).getStringCellValue();
                    String city = sh.getRow(j).getCell(9).getStringCellValue();
                    String address = sh.getRow(j).getCell(10).getStringCellValue();
                    String email = sh.getRow(j).getCell(11).getStringCellValue();
                    String skills = sh.getRow(j).getCell(12).getStringCellValue();

                    employee.setOperation(operation);
                    employee.setEmployeeId(id);
                    employee.setFirstName(firstName);
                    employee.setLastName(lastName);
                    employee.setAge(age);
                    employee.setGender(gender);
                    employee.setSalary(salary);
                    employee.setDepartment(department);
                    employee.setState(state);
                    employee.setCity(city);
                    employee.setAddress(address);
                    employee.setEmail(email);
                    employee.setSkillSet(skills);

                    System.out.println(firstName+"  ftyg");  //fine
                    employeeList.add(employee);
                }
                else
                {
                    int id = (int)sh.getRow(j).getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
                    employee.setOperation(operation);
                    employee.setEmployeeId(id);
                    employeeList.add(employee);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (EncryptedDocumentException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<employeeList.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(employeeList.get(i).getFirstName());
            //Rohit  Rohit
        }

    }

}
```

At the time of storing it prints the actual data. After storing it displays same data. For e.g:- My output comes like Rohit Rohit
My excel looks like :-

```
Operation   ID  FirstName   LastName    Age Gender  Salary  Department  State   City    Address Email   Skills
ADD     Nandn   Kumar   19  Male    32000   IT  UttarPradesh    Lucknow Birsa Road  nand00@gmail.com    JAVA, SQL
ADD     Rohit   Kumar   21  Male    25000   IT  UttarPradesh    Agra    Hanuman Gali    ro67@gmail.com  JAVA, SQL, J2EE
```

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints? Inside the `Employee` class or on the `employeeList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
employeeList.add(employee);
```

You keep adding the very **same** Employee object all the time.

Instead: create a completely **new** Employee object, and keep adding these **different** objects to your list!

What you do:

- take a piece of paper, to write stuff on that
- then you put that piece of paper into a binder
- then you fetch **that** paper again, and you write **new** stuff onto it
- you stuff the page into the binder
- then you fetch **that** paper again, and you write **new** stuff onto it...

Comment: Man, I am getting your point. But suppose i have 10 records then for every records, i have to create new object. Thanks for replying man.

Comment: @ShibuPrasad I think you dont understand. Each time your code has to deal with a **new** object, you create a new object. Creating new objects is the essence of OOP. Your approach of using 1 object, and updating its internal state (fields) ... is the exact opposite of good OOP. You dont need to create one new object per record. You create one object that holds the 10 record values.

Answer (score 1):

You've created an object called `employee` in the first line of your class. Inside the loop, you assign data to this object that you read in from the spreadsheet, and then you add this object to the list.

The second time this loops round, that *same* object is changed with the new data that is read in from the spreadsheet, and then is added to the list. So, now the list contains two objects, which both have the same **reference** (essentially you just have two labels in your list, but they're for the same thing). This means that when you change the object the second time round, it updates the information for all objects of it that exist - i.e. the ones that are already in the list!

**This is easily fixed**; instead of creating one `Employee` object at the beginning of your class, you can create an `Employee` object inside your `for` loop at the top. This way, each time you go through your loop, you will create a brand new `Employee` object which will capture the different data that you want as you iterate through. Hopefully the code snippet below helps to illustrate what I mean:

```java
public class ExcelHelper 
{   
    // Employee employee = new Employee(); // **REMOVE THIS LINE**
    ... // details omitted
        for(int j=1; j<=noOfRows; j++)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            ... // details omitted
}
```

Hope this helps!